# Circle collision with a specific tile on a grid

Tags: android, collision-detection

Does anyone know of a good tutorial that will show collision detection on a 2d game platform without using any engines?

Comment: http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/contains some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a book about mathematics, like Eric Lengyel, Mathematics for 3D Computer Graphics. 
Real Time rendering book website has a lot of intersection methods and their mathematics.